# YouTube data API list video by ID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the [youtube api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples) java code to list video by ID. I used the Topics.java file but it gives more than 1 result which includes the correct one. Also it does not apply the video ID (when I printed it gives the video ID as 0) and so I gave the video ID for the search term as well. Below is the screenshot of the inputs and output.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is getting exact one result for the given video ID like how it works on the [YouTube Data API code snippet](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets).

Am I running the wrong code or am I giving wrong inputs? Please advise.

**Update:** File VideoLocalizations.java throws null pointer exception for "language"
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Topics.java` file is demo-ing the [Topics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic), which I think is more than you want to do.

To simply get the details for a video ID, check out [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). You can use the API Explorer at the bottom of the page to create a basic request, e.g.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
    part=id%2Csnippet&id=5vY8EWokf40&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

...which returns:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/v-nx5E3jmblZ7cA3yNCjAAKmywQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/rsLwePwmFcmdkMVDPrQB20sLp1Q\"",
   "id": "5vY8EWokf40",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-27T03:02:46.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCz0Am9KlCDydaIifIL16hfw",
    "title": "Hajar Film - Sirin Hamsho | فيلم هاجر - سيرين حمشو",
...
```

To do this in Java, look at the Examples section on the same page. Essentially, you'll need to create a `com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube` object, call `videos().list()`, and handle the `VideoListResponse`.

Looking at the JAVA #2 example, you can see this demonstrated as:

```
// This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-localizations-sample").build();

...

// Call the YouTube Data API's videos.list method to retrieve videos.
VideoListResponse videoListResponse = youtube.videos().
    list("snippet,localizations").setId(videoId).execute();

// Since the API request specified a unique video ID, the API
// response should return exactly one video. If the response does
// not contain a video, then the specified video ID was not found.
List<Video> videoList = videoListResponse.getItems();
if (videoList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Can't find a video with ID: " + videoId);
    return;
}
Video video = videoList.get(0);
```

You can look at the [JavaDoc reference for the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/) for more details on using the Java library.

Comment: There is an error importing com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoLocalization. Please refer to the updated question with the screenshot of the command line.

Comment: Fixed the above by adding the 176 release which was referring to 107 before. But still it throws a null pointer exception on line 193. The question is updated with a screenshot.